# Generate JSON string of Magento's categories and children categories from PHP

Tags: php, json, magento

I'm trying to generate a JSON string that includes the id and url for all my categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories. The code below only gets me as far as the top-level category, but I also need the second and third as well. My goal is to create a dynamically updating sitemap that decodes the string and makes an unordered list of every category level.

```
public function createCategoryTree() {
$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter()->addLevelFilter(2)->addOrderField('position'); // load all categories
$arr = array();
if ($_categories){ // if there are categories
  foreach ($_categories as $cat){
    $cat_name = $cat->getName(); // name as key
    if (strlen(stristr($cat_name,'default')) < 3) {
      $cat_id = $cat->getId(); // id
      $cat_url = $cat->getUrl(); // url
      $arr[$cat_id] = array('title'=>$cat_name,'url'=>$cat_url); 
    }
  }
}
print_r (json_encode($arr));
die;
}
```

I get something like this:

```
{
    "637": {
        "title": "bikes",
        "url": "http:www.123.com/shop/bicycles "
    }
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
{
    "637": {
        "title": "bikes",
        "url": "http:www.123.com/shop/bicycles",
        "children": {
            "658": {
                "title":"wheels",
                "url":"http:www.123.com/shop/bicycles/wheels"
            },
            "489": {
                "title": "pumps",
                "url":"http:www.123.com/shop/bicycles/pumps"
            }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some functionality provided by `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` for this. See if this script works for you:

```
<?php
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

function getCategoryTree($recursionLevel, $storeId = 1)
{
    $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();    
    $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */

    $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
        ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
        ->getChildren();
    $tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent);

    $categoryTreeData = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $categoryTreeData[$node->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($node);
    }

    return $categoryTreeData;
}

function getNodeChildrenData(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
{
    $data = array(
        'title' => $node->getData('name'),
        'url'   => $node->getData('url_key'),
    );

    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $childNode) {
        if (!array_key_exists('children', $data)) {
            $data['children'] = array();
        }

        $data['children'][$childNode->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($childNode);
    }
    return $data;
}

print_r(json_encode(getCategoryTree(3)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't got it working exactly as I need it to yet, but you put me on a path to understanding the way to get there better and I feel close to getting it to work now. I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help! - perhaps you should accept the answer for others who have similar issues, or tell us what else you are missing so we can continue helping you out.

Comment: Got it! Sorry, still new to Stack. I'm going to tease out some of these syntax errors and get back here with any questions I still have in a few hours.